# Qt how to translate string to function?

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to translate a string (QString) from a literal into a function and call it?

For example, I have the a string containing "clicked", I want to translate this into a function and call it, something like:

```
eval("clicked")()
```

Comment: Where would this function be hosted? The literal answer to your question is to  create a `std::map<string, std::function<void()>>` to store your functions, then look them up and call them. I'm assuming your `clicked` function is actually implemented on some object that derives from `QObject`, in which case you can [ask Qt to invoke named slots for you](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course you can: you have in fact 2 options,

create a Map with string, function. and get the value by key and invoke it

or(a little bit more complex)

the methods must be of a classs that inherits the QObject class
and the methods are  slots or "invokable" functions,

and you need to use the

QMetaObject::invokeMethod method...

example:

```
FOO::MyClass obj;
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&obj, "foo", Qt::DirectConnection);
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was thinking of!

Comment: If I was to create a map what type would the signal be?

Comment: Its been suggested over on the Qt forum to use QSignalMapper, looking into this now.

Comment: Looking at the examples on the QSignalMapper page, it doesn't make sense to me and I see no examples of using a string to map to a function.

Comment: How can I create a map that will give me any signal based on using a text lookup?

Comment: I tried using: QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, pobjSignal->strGetSignal(), Qt::DirectConnection), but I get the warning:  no matching function call to 'invokeMethod'

Comment: I want to be able to use any signal for any Qt control, the idea is that a string is supplied and translated into the corresponding signal function.

Comment: I have now realised that what I want to do isn't possible, so I will have to implement conditional logic for each object type and compare the various strings.